# Problem in my code the script is not working

Tags: javascript

```
<head>
  <script>
    document.getElementById("count-el").innertext = 3
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>People entered</h1>
  <h2 id="count-el">0</h2>

</body>
</html>
```

innertext is not getting changed from 0 to 3.

Comment: _"innertext is not getting changed..."_ - Because there's an error in the console.

Comment: First you should pur `script` tab in the last of the body but before the end of `</body>` tag and second there is no such `innertext`, You should use `innerText`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues.

1. The <*script*> tag should be inside your <*body*>, ideally at the bottom.
2. You have spelled `innerText` incorrectly.

alternatively, you can use `innerHTML` or `textContent` as well

```js
document.getElementById("count-el").innerText = 3
```

```html
<h1>People entered</h1>
<h2 id="count-el">0</h2>
```

```
<body>
  <h1>People entered</h1>
  <h2 id="count-el">0</h2>

<script>
  document.getElementById("count-el").innerText = 3
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: The error on the console is "*Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerText' of null*". This occurs even if `innerText` is spelled correctly.

The reason is that the `document.getElementById("count-el").innerText = 3` is executed before the `count-el` element was rendered by the browser. To fix this, wait until the DOM is ready before running the script.

Comment: You have two problems on your code, the first one is that your script is not being invoked by your `html body`, because it's only defined in the `html head`; the second problem is the property you're accessing, use `innerHTML` instead of `innertext`:

`function change_data(){document.getElementById("count-el").innerHTML = 3}`


...


`<body onload="change_data();">`